# Fatal error memory limit (always) while installing a module

Tags: composer, 9

I am asking for help in solving an extremely annoying problem. I have a simple website based on Drupal 9. Due to its simplicity, the installation of all modules was based on the Drupal UI. I also have one small module of my own that creates several blocks.

When I try to add libraries to the ReCatpcha module via Composer, I still have an error:

> Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar:///home/myaccount/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleWatchGraph.php

I have 512M of memory on the server. I would like to add that everything works fine on a clean Drupal 9 installation, modules are added correctly. On this page, however, it is possible to update Drupal 9 via Composer, but you cannot add any modules.

I was looking for a solution on the Internet, but there are only possibilities to increase the available memory to '-1' => no limit. It is not an option for me.

I will just add that I can not install any module. I always have the same message.

I suspect that Composer is not coping with something, but it won't say what. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: You don't need to increase the memory limit globally. You simply can increase it for the time calling `composer` via `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer install -n`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the same error still exists. I wonder why here in this case Composer needs so much memory. On a different domain, on a clean installation, Composer installs modules very quickly and without any problems.

Comment: Which version of Composer? Have you installed zaporylie/composer-drupal-optimizations, If not, are able to do so - and does it help?

Comment: try with `php -d memory_limit=-1 PATH/composer install`

Comment: Ok the problem seems to be solved. On the server where I have the domain, the PHP (global) version is set to 7.2. The domain itself is set to PHP 7.4. I had to call composer.phar by running the PHP7.4 version path (something like usr / bin / php / 74) and everything worked fine.

Why on PHP 7.2, Composer didn't want to work, only threw this exception?

Thanks very, very much for your help!!!

Comment: _Why on PHP 7.2_ different php versions on the same machine almost always use different php.ini files, maybe the memory limit in the 7.2 one is too low